# Probability puzzle

Tags: probability

Find the probability of drawing 4 white balls and 2 black balls without replacement from a bag containing 1 red, 4 black, and 6 white balls.

My logic is $\dfrac{\dbinom{6}{4}\,\cdot\!\dbinom{4}{2}}{\dbinom{11}{6}}$

The given answer is 15/17. What is wrong here ?

There are 15 ways to arrange 4 white balls and 2 black balls without replacement. $\dfrac{6!}{4!\cdot 2!}$. But I cannot think further.... :(

BTW, how to $\,^{11}\mathrm{C}_6$ in $\LaTeX$ without using \binom ? What about $\,^{11}\mathrm{P}_6$?

Comment: There are 15 ways to arrange 4 white balls and 2 black balls without replacement. $\frac{6!}{4!*2!}$. But I cannot think further.... :(

Comment: Hi, the answer you gave by your logic is right and it simplifies to $\frac{15\cdot 6}{462}=\frac{15}{77}$.

Comment: \,^{11}C_{6} gives $\,^{11}C_6$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by your logic is correct. 15/17 looks like a typo for 15/77.

11C6 - How do you want it to be? $_{11}C_{6}$ or $^{11}C_6$.

Comment: There are 15 ways to arrange 4 white balls and 2 black balls without replacement. $\frac{6!}{4!*2!}$. But I cannot think further.... :(

Comment: @user148176 : The order does not matter. Take it as a hypergeometric distribution.

Answer (score 0):

There are $_{6}C_{4}=15$ combinations of four red balls and $_{4}C_{2}=6$ combinations of two black balls. We must do more than multiply these two binomials together though, because BBRRRR is a different arrangement than RBRBRR. The black balls can be drawn in two of the six positions, so we must account for the $_{6}C_{2}$ arrangements of four red and two black balls. Therefore, there are
$$
 \binom{6}{4}\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{2}=64800
$$
possibilities.

There are $_{11}P_{6}=(11)(10)(9)(8)(7)(6)=332640$ ways to draw six balls from the bag without replacement, so the probability of drawing four red and two black balls is
$$
\frac{\binom{6}{4}\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{2}}{_{11}P_{6}} = \frac{64800}{332640} = \frac{15}{77}.
$$